# Why is my JDBC connection only failing when deployed through Jetty?

Tags: java, jdbc, web-applications, jetty

To pretense, i'm new to web development. I have a java web application that is deployed through Jetty, and I have an issue that is really confusing me. In order to display data from my database in the web app I must establish a database connection, which I can do when I am unit testing my code, but when I call the same methods from .jsp pages to populate the web app I get a message telling me this:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;integratedSecurity=true;database=TicketITBookingSystemDatabase;loginTimeout=30;
```

Here is the rest of the relevant code:

```
public void queryDatabase(String query){

ResultSet resultSet = null;
String connectionUrl = establishDatabaseConnection();

try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
     Statement statement  = connection.createStatement();) {

    //Execute the sql statement passed as the query parameter.
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
    processResultSet(resultSet);
    statement.close();
}
// Handle any errors that may have occurred.
catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); //why is this being hit but only on the web build
}
```

And the event that is being called:

```
public List<String[]> getAllEvents(){
    queryDatabase("EXEC dbo.sp_GetAllEventDetails");
    return events;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a build error, actually.  Maybe the JDBC JAR is not making it into the classpath of the application which is being run on Jetty.  You should check of this.  By the way, if you're testing an actual database, then it's not a unit test, it's an _integration_ test.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the guidance, Tim. Do you know how I would check the classpath?

Comment: Open up your WAR/JAR and poke around.  Something like `jar -tvf your_jar.jar` should work.

Comment: Don't use `DriverManager` in a web application. Use a properly configured datasource instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the driver of the database on the classpath of Jetty.

Check if it is present or not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that either you did not add the driver jar to the classpath of Jetty, or - if you deployed it with the application - you need to load the driver explicitly with `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")`. JDBC automatic driver loading only works when the driver is on the initial classpath, not if it is on a context classpath.

However, it is generally inadvisable to use `DriverManager` directly from a web application. The use of a `DataSource` is usually better, especially if the data source implementation provides a connection pool.